# How to pass a 'main-parameter' to a member-function

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm writing a tiny Console Messanger with the Winsock library, but how do i pass the 'char* argv[]' parameter from main to a memberfunction?

I have defined and declared a class where all the things for setting up the client are done(starting socket, initialising...). This Class is written in another document, but i need to make a member-function be able to access the char* argv[] parameter when the function is called in main()

```
int CWinsock::Connect(/*pass argv here*/) {
  printf("Connect to port\nPort: ");
  std::cin >> m_port;//get port
  memset(&m_addr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
  m_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  m_addr.sin_port = htons(m_port);//Connect to port

  m_rc = getAddrFromString(argv[1], &m_addr);//Get the IP adress
```

the argv parameter is used right above

```
if (m_rc == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("IP not found!\n");
    return 1;
}else
    printf("IP found!\n");
...
}//Connect
```

Comment: Your function uses a single string (the first command line parameter passed to `main`) and should be declared thus. You can use a C string: `int CWinsock::Connect(char *param) {/* ... */ getAddrFromString(param, &m_addr);` If you use a C++ `std::string` you'd write  `int CWinsock::Connect(std::string param) {/* ... */ getAddrFromString(param.c_str(), &m_addr);`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need

```
int CWinsock::Connect(const char* adress)
{
    //..
    m_rc = getAddrFromString(adress, &m_addr);//Get the IP adress 
    //..
}
```

and in `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char**argc)
{
    // ..
    CWinsock winsock{/*..*/};
    // ..
    int res = winsock.Connect(argv[1]);
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward

```
int CWinsock::Connect(char** argv) {
```

or (same thing)

```
int CWinsock::Connect(char* argv[]) {
```

Am I missing something?